How do I list certificates in personal store across all servers in domain
I need to get a list of all of the certificates in the personal store across all of the servers in my domain. I am currently using the following powershell command which provides the desired results
Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine\my | Export-Csv \\filepath\filename.csv

However this requires me to go into each server and run the command. how do I avoid doing so?
I used the following to create a csv file aof all of the server names to iterate through
get-adcomputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object name | export-csv -NoType $ExportPath

all of the servers are in a specific OU which is the value of the %OUPath  variable.
Here is the script I have tried, however it does not give me the certificate data I am looking for.
$OUpath = 'OU=Servers,OU=someOU,DC=somedomain,DC=com'
$ExportPath = '\\filepath\ServerList.csv'
get-adcomputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object name | export-csv -NoType $ExportPath

import-csv $exportpath
foreach-object{
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine\my | Export-Csv -append -path \\filepath\certlist.csv
    }

there are over 500 servers in the OU yet the file only has 30 rows, and is missing pertinent information regarding the cert for each server.
I am looking for the following headers
DnsNameList FriendlyName    NotAfter    NotBefore   HasPrivateKey   Issuer

I can connect to each machine and run Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine\my | Export-Csv -append -path
to export the file locally but it would be more helpful if i could append a document on the network share.

Are you an Admin on all the remote machines?  You probably have Group Policy enforced and do not have the permission.  Check with a Group Policy Admin.

Yes I am the admin on all of the machines in the OU. I have recently removed exporting the computer names to a csv and did the following
$OUpath = 'OU=Servers,OU=someOU,DC=somedomain,DC=com'
$ExportPath = '\filepath\certlist.csv'
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object distinguishedname
foreach ($computer in $Computers)
{
Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine\My #| Export-Csv  -path $ExportPath -force
}
Which still give me the incorrect results

the registry I think needs two backslashes so it starts at the top \localmachine

Here is the final code that produced the desired results
$OUpath = 'OU=Servers,OU=someOU,DC=somedomain,DC=com'
$command = {Get-ChildItem Cert:\localmachine\My | select friendlyname, dnsnamelist, NotAfter, NotBefore, thumbprint, Issuer, Subject, HasPrivateKey | Format-Table -groupby dnsnamelist -autosize }
$list = Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | select-object -expand name                                     #Creates a list of servers from the Servers AD OU
ForEach($name in $list)  #Loops through each name in the list, pulls the Certificate information, and appends it to a .csv file
{
   if ($name -NotLike 'SomeServerName')
      {
        $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $name
        invoke-command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $command -AsJob
        $job = Get-Job
        $job|Receive-Job -Keep > \\SomeOutputFile.csv         #Gets the output of the remote job,and exports to a .csv file
       }
{
get-job | remove-job    #Cleans up all jobs created by script
get-PSSession | remove-PSSession    #cleans up all remote sessions created by script

                                                                                  


I'm not too sure where to start, your script will not work as is. You will have to work invoke-command into your script.
This is a oneline that could get you started:
get-adcomputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object -expand name | foreach-object {invoke-command -computername $_ -scriptblock {get-childitem Cert:\localmachine\my | select friendlyname, dnsnamelist}}


Oh man! thank you so much. this was the path that I was on. I kept getting this error when I tried using Invoke-command  " One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings."
I think what you have poseted will work. I will give it a try and see what happens.

your breadcrumbs lead me down this path as a test, and it is producing the results that I want.
$command = {Get-Culture}
$list = Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | select-object -expand name
foreach($name in $list)
{
invoke-command -ComputerName $name -ScriptBlock $command
}
